# Strange cast error in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have these classes:

```
public class A <T>{
}

public interface I {    
}

public class X implements I {
}

public class B extends A<X>{
}
```

In my code if I do it i get error:

```
A<I> myobj = (A<I>) new B();
```

It must be:

```
A<X> myobj = (A<X>) new B();
```

But if I do it is ok and works well:

```
A<I> myobj = null;
myobj  = (A<I>) Class.forName("B").newInstance();
```

In this last case i access all methods of B and works very fine.

I need declare myobj as A because I only guarantee the interface of generic obj not the class specifically.

Anyone know why my first case don't works?

I would like to implemente the first due be most elegant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit

Comment: cast to A<? extends I> instead of A<I>

Comment: Thanks everyone A<? extends I> works well and my code became more elegant :). But I'm still confused with last case :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way generics work in Java. Class String implements interface CharSequence, but you can't cast List<CharSequence> to List<String> (or vice versa). But you can cast ArrayList<String> to List<String> (and List<String> to ArrayList<String> - at least compiler won't complain, but you'll get a runtime exception if your List object isn't an instance of ArrayList).

What if it were possible? Here's an example:

```
1. List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>(); // piece of cake!
2. List<Object> listOfObjects = (List<Object>) listOfString; // String is a subclass ofObject, so why not?
3. listOfObjects.add(new Object()); // obviously correct
4. String s = listOfString.get(0); // ouch! We've just put an Object into this list, but generic type promises there are only Strings!
```

This is why there's a compilation error in line 2. Of course, you can fool the compiler and try this:

```
A<I> myobj = null;
A genericA = new B();
myobj = (A<I>) genericA;
```

This will work because generic types are removed in the runtime. You can do this also with lists:

```
List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
List genericList = listOfStrings;
genericList.add(new Object());
String s = listOfStrings.get(0);
```

This code will compile (with warnings), but you will get an exception in the runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

This code:

```
myobj  = (A<I>) Class.forName("B").newInstance();
```

works, because method *newInstance()* returns an instance of java.lang.Object. Compiler has no idea what it will return in the runtime, so it allows casting it to everything. Because of the [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), in the runtime A<I> is just A, and since B is a subclass of A, you can cast an instance of B to A.